# how receive http response of binary pdf and show it. angular 2 - ionic2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I am tring to recive a pdf convert to binary(64) from a rest service, and show it in ionic 2, i try this:

I am tring to recive a pdf convert to binary(64) from a rest service, and show it in ionic 2, i try this:

```
    in service
    function(token:String, docCaseNumber: String){
      this.setTokenHeaders(token);
      this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/octet-stream');      
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });     
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get(url, options)
        .map(res => res)
        .subscribe(data => {
          //console.log(data);
            resolve(data.text());
          }, err => {
            resolve("connException");
          });
        }); 
    }
       in component
     getXX(){
      this.miservice.functoin(this.token, 'H17-09601').then(
          (data) => {
              var blob = data;
              console.log(blob);

              this.base64ToUint8Array(data);

              //this.getBase64(data);

              var converted = new Blob([blob], {type:'application/pdf'});
              this.convertToBase64(converted);
              //this.base64ToUint8Array(converted);
              //this.fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(converted);
              //window.open(fileURL);
              var pdf = pdfMake.createPdf(this.buildPdf(converted));

              pdf.getBase64(function (output) {
                this.base64ToUint8Array(output);
              });
              //console.log(pdf);
              pdf.open;
              //console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand _why_ you have posted a question with an answer. You should post a question which contains the problem as per [ask] and [mcve] and then post an answer with the solution. This is to help future readers and to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer. You can use this for show pdf
Modify according to your needs ;)

```
 return new Promise(resolve => {
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('get', url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/octet-stream');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
            // xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1');
            xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1');
            xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
            xhr.onreadystatechange= function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify((xhr.response)));
                        resolve(new Blob([xhr.response], { type: 'application/pdf' }));
                    } else {
                        //do something
                    }
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
            }); 
then use it like this:

    your-function.then(
              (blob :Blob) => {
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var downloadLink      = document.createElement('a');
                downloadLink.href = downloadUrl;
                downloadLink.target   = '_blank';
                document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                downloadLink.click();

              });
```